# Got wrong output in my task, cant solve it

Tags: java, for-loop

Hello i got one task to do. output should be like this:

```
{
0
0 1
0 2 4
0 3 6 9
0 4 8 12 16
0 5 10 15 20 25
0 6 12 18 24 30 36
0 7 14 21 28 35 42 49
0 8 16 24 32 40 48 56 64
0 9 18 27 36 45 54 63 72 81
}
```

I tried to do it: here is my code:

```
public class ContnueUzOznakoMojNacin 
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    int k=0, v=0;
    int j;
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        for(j=10-i;j<10;j++)
        {
            System.out.print(v+" ");
            v+=k;
        }
        System.out.println();
        v=0;
        k++;
    }
}
}
```

And the output i get is wrong and i dont get it why.
here it is:

```
{
0 
0 2 
0 3 6 
0 4 8 12 
0 5 10 15 20 
0 6 12 18 24 30 
0 7 14 21 28 35 42 
0 8 16 24 32 40 48 56 
0 9 18 27 36 45 54 63 72
}
```

When i follow these loops and increments from my program i cant find mistake.

first line is ok output should be 0;
but second line, output should be 0 1; not 0 2 ? 
I dont need you to give me code for this task i need you to help me to do it, to tell me where i made mistake so i do it on my own. Thanks :)

Answer (score 8):

Change this line:

```
for(j=10-i;j<10;j++)
```

to this:

```
for(j=9-i;j<10;j++)
```

And here's an explanation:

So `i` starts at `0`, right? What will be `i`'s maximum? `9`, because in `for(int i=0;i<10;i++)`, `i` cannot get to `10`.

Let's look at how that affects `for(j=10-i;j<10;j++)`. If `i` is `9` (the last row), then the `j` loop will only run `9` times. `j` will equal `1`,`2`,`3`,`4`,`5`,`6`,`7`,`8`,`9`. That's only 9 loops. If you look at the bottom of the upper triangle, you can see that `0 9 18 27 36 45 54 63 72` has only 9 numbers.

We want `j` to run 10 times, as you can see by the base of the correct triangle: `0 9 18 27 36 45 54 63 72 81`. How do we do this? We make `j` run one more time on every `i` loop, by decreasing the starting number (`10-i`) by one (which equals `9-i`). That is how you arrive at

```
for(j=9-i;j<10;j++)
```